# How to scrape infinitely scrolling websites with login using python request (or similar)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I would like to scrape a website that does not have an API and is an "infinite scroller". I have been using `selenium` for this, but now I need to scrape a lot more pages and do that all at once. The problem is that selenium is very resource-dependant since I am running a full (headless) chrome browser in each instance and also not stable at all (probably because of limited resources but still). I know that there is a way to look for `ajax` requests that the site uses and access it with `requests` library, but I have two issues:

1. I can't seem to find the desired request
2. The ones that I try to use with `requests` library require the user to be logged in and I have no idea how to do that (maybe pass cookies and whatnot, I am not a web developer).

Let me take Twitter as an example since it is exactly the as what I am describing (except it has an API). You have to log in and then the feed is loaded infinitely. So the goal is to "scroll" and take the content of each tweet. How can this be done? If you can, please, provide a working example.

Thank you.

Comment: Try beautifulsoup4 .. I personally use it for web scraping .

Comment: @httpanand I will be happy to try, but can you, please, specify how exactly should I use it to achieve the goal above.

Comment: In the browser, open the developer tab and check which request happens when loading the next "chunk". It will be something like page=2, page=3 and so on. Just do that same request in python, copying the parameters.

Comment: @LtWorf Yes, this is something that I want to do, however, there is no such thing on the website. Could you give an example of that for Twitter? it also does not have such a request. but maybe I am looking wrong.

Comment: not ON the website, in the browser, just use your browser's developer tools and see all the network traffic it does. There are pages, when you scroll down it triggers to load more. Just see what request is going out.

Comment: @LtWorf I know lol, I have suggested this in the question. There is no such request there, at least I can't find one or it is more complex than that. I would really appreciate it if you could show that to me on Twitter as an example.

Comment: @user9102437 Twitter uses a graphql database. You have to send a query string to ask for the next page.

Comment: @Invizi Thaks, I actually found it thanks to your clarification. However, I still don't understand just quite how it works since I couldn't reproduce it by myself. The issue is that I don't know how it "knows" which content to return. It has one weird parameter "cursor", but it seems to be encoded or something: "HBaKgLOFsoP+pykAAA==", maybe it is responsible

Comment: Try decoding it using a base 64 decoder.

Comment: @Invizi This was my first thought as well. Unfortunately, it is just jibberish.